# Failed install R package RMySQL on CentOS 6.5 "because mysql-connector-c was not found"

Tags: r, linux, centos

I'm installing RMySQL within R terminal under CentOS 6.5 but received the following error message:

```
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
** 成功将‘RMySQL’程序包解包并MD5和检查
Found INCLUDE_DIR and/or LIB_DIR!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib64/R/include/include
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lmysqlclient -lz
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because mysql-connector-c was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libmysqlclient-dev | libmariadbclient-dev (Debian, Ubuntu)
 * rpm: mariadb-devel | mysql-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: mysql56_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: mysql-connector-c (OSX)
If mysql-connector-c is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a mysql-connector-c.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RMySQL’
```

Here's additional info:

1. I've installed mysql-devel as required through yum
2. PKG_CONFIG_PATH has been set to "/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" however I'm unable to locate the file "mysql-connector-c.pc" on the entire system.

I've been stuck here for 2 days and would really appreciate your help and advice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can search for mysql-connector-c at http://rpm.pbone.net/ to get an overview.

Note that no mysql-connector-c packages are available for CentOS. Only appears when searching Redhat EL6 and EL7.

Also be aware that none of the "mysql-connector-c-devel" packages seems to have a file "mysql-connector-c.pc"